# What are the most effective ways to promote this site?

Tags: discussion

I was planning to spread the word at my local PMI chapter in San Diego, but I was just thinking that trying to get a write up on the main PMI.org site or in their monthly magazine would be even better.  Good idea? Terrible idea?

So as to not have a flood of PMI-centric contributions, what other equivalent organizations might we try to spread the word within?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any professional organizations would be a great way to spread the word.  However, it doesn't have to be specific to project management.  Lots of organizations and companies have project managers, and we're more likely to get better, more realistic questions from people who work as real project managers in real companies.

The one possible problem with PMI-centric organizations is that they may bring in people who are too rigid.  I was accused earlier of being more of a technical lead than a project manager and that my question was irrelevant.  At my company, a project manager is technical and does more than just typical PM tasks.  I'd hate to see the site become inflexible because a particular project management task doesn't fit the PMI definition of a project management task.

The job descriptions for a project manager will be different from company to company, and the site needs to be flexible in order to accomodate the majority of project manager roles.

**UPDATE:** Here are some other ways that we can promote the site:

- Create a Facebook page and link some of the questions from the site:  [Project Management Stack Exchange Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Project-Management-Stack-Exchange-QA/199284413419958?v=wall)
- Create a LinkedIn page, also linking some of the best questions.
- Twitter
- Blog posts about the launch that link back to the site and some of the questions, such as this example announcing that [Project Management Stack Exchange Begins Private Beta](http://blog.opensourceopportunities.com/2011/02/project-management-stack-exchange.html).

Comment: I agree 100%.  So, any thoughts on how to promote or techniques to try?

Comment: I don't live on Facebook, so if anyone wants to contribute to the Facebook page, is there a way to grant access?  It's created, for anyone who has more input or who wants to contribute.

Comment: @Dave - I added your website Web page on Project Management Stack Exchange to the [Project Management Stack Exchange Facebook page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Project-Management-Stack-Exchange-QA/199284413419958?v=wall).  If you get a write up done in pmi.org, send me the link, and I'll add that to the list of links in the Facebook page.

Comment: I'm a facebook noob, but I really like what you've done there, jmort253.  Did you set that up as a group in facebook? http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=414.  Not sure if that would be better or worse.

Comment: @Dave - I'm not yet sure the advantages or disadvantages either.  I think the group would be more about associating people, whereas I get the impression the page is more about the site itself.  Maybe the group and the page can be linked?  I think this will clearly take more investigating on my end.  If anyone has any suggestions as to which is better, please let me know.

Comment: @Dave - The [PM Stackexchange Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/pages/Project-Management-Stack-Exchange-QA/199284413419958?v=wall) should be the choice for promoting this site if choosing between a Facebook Page or a Facebook Group.  I asked a question on Pro Webmasters, [What is the Difference Bwtween a Facebook Page and a Facebook Group?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9389/what-is-the-difference-between-a-facebook-group-and-a-facebook-page/9391#9391)  Please see the responses.  I'm not sure yet if it's helpful to have both a page and a group.

Comment: Got it.  Based on those responses, I think the fb page works better - we are just trying to spread the word, not spawn a whole other discussion forum, etc - we want people to come here to do that!

Answer (score 2):

PMI is a great start (not everyone there is dogmatically PMI-centric).

[ASAPM](http://www.asapm.org) is another pm focused organization.

Let major pm-podcasts know about it (e.g. The Project Management Podcast, PM411, Project Management War Stories).

Professional trade groups like [SAE](http://www.sae.org), [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org), [Construction Institue](http://www.construction-institute.org/), etc.